# Copying entire field to another worksheet

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I created a table in the first worksheet, where row 1 are the headers and row 2 onwards is the data.

I want to copy the first field [ProjectCode] into a second worksheet, i.e. copy EVERY record. In the cell A6 of the second worksheet I want to paste the row data from the sixth row onwards.

in A6 I referenced the first worksheet,and field [ProjectCode]  but it gives me the data from the fifth row.

If I copy the formula to A7, i'll get the sixth row. I want rows1-4, and I dont want to move the table up in the second worksheet. any help?

Answer (score 0):

if you click on the A column, you select the whole column. then copy and paste it into A5 of the next worksheet. A5 because you want your data to get from A6 downwards. A5 would be the description, A6 and so on data